# maildev not catching sendmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have an Ubuntu with **sendmail** and **maildev** installed.
I'm running maildev :

```
$ maildev
MailDev webapp running at http://0.0.0.0:1080
MailDev SMTP Server running at 0.0.0.0:1025
```

I'm using PHP to send mail :

```
mail('myMail@gmail.com','test Mail ' . __FILE__,'test','From:me@my_domain.com');
```

with **php.ini** :

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 1025
```

However, the mail is not catched by maildev, sendmail is sending it and I got it on my real mail "myMail@gmail.com" (it does not appear on  http://0.0.0.0:1080)

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you changed `localhost` to be `0.0.0.0` instead? Localhost is typically only bound to `127.0.0.1 & ::1`

Comment: Hello, if you use the mail function in PHP and then your mail send to sendmail system function and  finally you receive this mail in your real mailbox it means that maybe have been installed and configured Mail server for example postfix. You should check if The Postfix is installed and configure him not to send mail to real mailbox via SMTP

Comment: @hppycoder, I tried your point but no effect. Maildev is listening to 0.0.0.0 (so everything so localhost too)

Comment: @AlexandrBlyakher I don't have `postfix`, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Change Maildev to listen to 127.0.0.1, then try again